# Why the compiler does not recognize Google Mock wildcard?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

When I try to use:

```
ON_CALL(mock, foo(_))
```

Compilation error is thrown:

```
Error   1   error C2065: '_' : undeclared identifier
```

I am using visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**undeclared identifier** always means that compiler does not understand what it (i.e. _) is. So perhaps you forgot

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
```

or

```
using::testing::_;
```

Refer to examples and check.

Comment: or `using namespace testing`

Comment: or `using ::testing::DoAll;`